# How to open a Windows filepath?

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I'm trying to... simply open a .csv file of data but the filepath just won't work no matter what I try. It just keeps giving me an error either with double back slashes or the back slash missing with the characters after missing.

As stupid as it sounds, I'm trying to open a compressed zip file from a folder, but I keep getting silly errors.

```
import pandas as pd
import os

PATH = os.path.join('data', 'binance_data', 'data', 'spot', 'daily', 'klines', 'BTCUSD', '5m', '2023-01-01_2023-02-01', 'BTCUSDT-5m-2023-01-01')
print(PATH)
```

Which gives me the follow output:

```
data\binance_data\data\spot\daily\klines\BTCUSD\5m\2023-01-01_2023-02-01\BTCUSDT-5m-2023-01-01
```

But then I try to open with pandas and...

```
dataset = pd.read_csv(PATH, compression='zip', header=None)

FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'data\\binance_data\\data\\spot\\daily\\klines\\BTCUSD\\5m\\2023-01-01_2023-02-01\\BTCUSDT-5m-2023-01-01'
```

I get the same error when I try:

```
"data\binance_data\data\spot\daily\klines\BTCUSD\5m\2023-01-01_2023-02-01\BTCUSDT-5m-2023-01-01"
```

Except it randomly swaps out some of the characters behind ONLY some of the backslashes.

I just want to open a file, this shouldn't take 2 hours.

Comment: (1) Use an absolute path instead. A relative one may not point to the expected location. (2) To write a path directly, prepend the string with `r`, like `r"data\binance_data\data\spot\daily\..."`. Be aware that such a raw string must not end with a single backslash. (3) Internal file functions on Windows can cope with forward slashes instead. Only if the shell (e.g. cmd.exe) is involved, backslashes are necessary,

Comment: @MichaelButscher this made progress but now I'm getting 'permission denied' error.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that you are looking for a file called "**BTCUSDT-5m-2023-01-01**" with extension "**.csv**" in the directory **data\binance_data\data\spot\daily\klines\BTCUSD\5m\2023-01-01_2023-02-01**, you simply need to add "**.csv**" at the end of your text AKA file path.

Like this

```
path = r"data\binance_data\data\spot\daily\klines\BTCUSD\5m\2023-01-01_2023-02-01\BTCUSDT-5m-2023-01-01.csv"
df = pd.read_csv(path, compression='zip', header=None)
```

will work

Comment: This works if I unzip the file, though I need to add one more file at the end. So path = r"data\binance_data\data\spot\daily\klines\BTCUSD\5m\2023-01-01_2023-02-01BTCUSDT-5m-2023-01-01\BTCUSDT-5m-2023-01-01.csv". Sorry didn't specify that the csv was inside the last folder.
Wish I didn't have to unzip but oh well.

Answer (score 1):

#### Are you sure that you are on the compressed drive?

You appear to be not specifying a drive, so perhaps it defaults to your working drive?

I would expect the path for a separate drive to start with the drive letter, e.g.

```
E:\data\...
```

#### What happens when you display the directory via `DIR` in the command console?

In CMD.exe or similar, what does this give you?

```
DIR "E:\data\binance_data\data\spot\dail..."
```

#### Or by "compressed drive" do you mean "inside a ZIP file"?

Because I note you mentioned `compression="zip"` in your CSV-reading command. Is it in a ZIP file, inside a compressed drive? Or is that a red herring?

Comment: The last folder is zipped, the csv file is inside.